# JMX Jconsole not finding Application

Tags: java, jmx, jconsole

I recently written an Application with an MBean, this was working fine a couple of days. Now when it is running, I can't see it using JConsole. Even though I add this to my run arguments: `-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote`
I tried other programs like: JVisualVM and JRockit mission control, but none of them see the application. What is more, I used to be able to see the other programs as well, like Jconsole could see JVisualVM, but even this is not working sadly. Does anyone know what went wrong?
Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I finally got it working, it worked when I started jconsole using cmd. Later I found out the problem. For some reason I didn't have the right permissions on this folder: %TMP%\hsperfdata_username. Just deleting and recreating solved it for me, for anyone who has the same problem ;)

Comment: Thank you very much. This also helped in my question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19663495/cannot-see-eclipse-processes-with-jconsole